# Check for errors raised by Google Sheets onOpen function

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a very simple piece of code.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    installTrigger();

    ui.createMenu('Data Processing')
        .addItem('Check emails', 'getSSMessagesApp')
        .addToUi();

  }

  function installTrigger() {
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    Logger.log(allTriggers.length);

    if(allTriggers.length < 1) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('getSSMessagesApp')
        .timeBased()
        .everyHours(6)
        .create();
    }
  }
```

If I simply run either `onOpen` or `installTrigger` from the Script Editor, it works fine and creates trigger and menu.

However, if I reopen the spreadsheet, the function fails to install the trigger. It even doesn't create the menu. I assume there's some error but don't know what is it and how to get any info about it.

What might be the cause and is it possible to check `onOpen` errors?

Comment: Stackdriver will log exceptions if you have that option enabled (by default I believe it is).

Comment: Note that you need to review the restrictions applied to simple triggers (functions using reserved names).

Comment: Thanks for StackDriver. Indeed the error is there. You can post it as answer and I will accept.